# Getting System.IO.FileNotFoundException with MaxQuant running on Linux with mono

Tags: maxquant

I am getting this error with MaxQuant 1.6.14 running with mono (5.14.0.177=he1b5a44_1001).

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/home/ubuntu/run-dir/combined/combinedRunInfo"

And I not sure why I am getting this error. The process has read and write permissions to that location.

Answer (score 1):

...seems the mqpar file was not compatible with the maxquant version.

Make sure the `mqpar.xml` file shows the same version number as the MaxQuant binary.
`MaxQuant` is not really made for the command line. So, the errors shown are sometimes quite misleading.